# add existing user does not show checkbox to select user on itunesconnect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I have uploaded one app via `Xcode` on the store. After that I went to itunesconnect.com and login with Apple ID.

Then clicked on `My Apps -> Select my app -> TestFlight`.

Clicked on Version of app which I want to test. And `Provide Compliance` and `Start Internal Testing`.

Now I need to add tester, clicked on `Add Existing Users`, but It is not showing checkbox.

Can anyone know about this ? I have tried by many time refresh the page, logout and login again, via different browsers, but no any luck.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: @trojanfoe Then can you suggest me where I have to post this question ?

Comment: Isn't the reason you can't add them that they are already added as testers to this build? They seem to be invited, or have already installed.

Comment: @VRAwesome I assume the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: @andlin Tester's email ID were already there because I have added them for other apps as well. But when I try to add here, they have shown as suggestion, but there should be checkbox, but can't seen.

Comment: Is this for internal or external tests? If external, maybe you must submit the build and have it approved to be able to add testers? UPDATE: Sorry, just realised that you wrote it's internal...

Comment: @trojanfoe I want quick answer, not sure only there I can get answer.

Comment: @andlin Internal testing.